# Two vectors of exchangeable random variables are identically distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider the vectors $Y:=(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3)$ and $W:=(W_1,W_2, W_3)$, where $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3, W_1, W_2, W_3$ are random variables.

Assume $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3, W_1, W_2, W_3$ are exchangeable with the meaning stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables)

Does this imply that $Y$ is distributed as $W$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because $(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, W_1, W_2, W_3)$ has the same joint distribution as $(W_1, W_2, W_3, Y_1, Y_2, Y_3)$.